# d3 v4 charts alternate x axis

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Display alternate x axis labels in d3 line chart or show only odd number position x axis labels.

I'm using d3 chart v4.

Below is my testing code - d3 graph gallery code..

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }))
    .range([ 0, width ]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));
```

Sample code link - https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_several_group.html